# Which is slower, jpeg or png?

Tags: c++, c, libjpeg, libpng

I was wondering if there is a significant difference in the decompression process of these two types of image: Which is slower, JPEG or PNG?

Comment: Which is slower, playing poker, or playing chess? It depends on the players - just like which compression method is slower depends on the software.

Comment: Well, JPEG quality 100 will be near instant as nothing is actually being compressed!  You need to refine your question further.  Actually, you should probably just throw it out.  Why?  JPEG and PNG compression are made to work on different types of inputs.  Have something like a real life image (i.e., a photo of yourself)?  Use JPEG, that's what it was made for.  A computer generated image should not be compressed with JPEG however and PNG is a much better choice.  The question itself shows a lack of understanding on the subject.

Comment: Wow, tough crowd. Clearly the first thing you didn't know (and that you should be aware of by having asked the question) is that it depends on some things. Ed's answer is a good start in telling you what it depends on. I don't thing the chess and poker answer was too helpful, though. ;~)

Comment: It is not a real world scenario, and I am not going to change the format on performance, it was just something I was wondering and though it would be a good question to discuss with the community...

Comment: @EdS., even at 100% JPEG is still encoded with DCT. I don't think the compression quality matters at all, except that low quality means a smaller file which means fewer bytes to read!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The many commenters here who say "it depends" are wrong. PNG decompression is always slower than JPG decompression, in every study that has been reported. Plus I personally have verified this in several different projects.

There is no such thing as an uncompressed PNG, despite greg's assertion to the contrary. All PNGs are compressed, and the compression of all PNGs is lossless. And decompressing all PNGs is sorta slow, compared to comparable JPGs.

All JPGs are compressed too, but JPG compression is always lossy. In particular, JPEG at 100 quality is NOT uncompressed. Quality 100 still has lossy compression, despite Ed S.'s assertion to the contrary. Please stop upvoting his comment.

Comment: "All PNGs are compressed" -- true, the only format for IDAT chunks is "compressed". But the algorithm used (zlib deflate) allows "no" compression: "Level 0 actually does no compression at all, and in fact expands the data slightly" (http://www.zlib.net/zlib_how.html). A fact I have used to easily create valid PNG images from raw data.

Answer (score 1):

There are way too many factors at play here.  Consider the two formats.  PNG images *if compressed* are compressed with `zlib`, which is a lossless compression.  Therefore, you could measure the performance of decompression of PNG based on the decompression rate of `zlib`.  PNGs do **not** have to be compressed though (no `zlib` compression performed).

JPEG is a completely and utterly different beast.  There are dozens of different encodings of JPEGs, not to mention JPEG-Lossless.  There is JPEG arithmetic encodings (formerly patented) and the more common JPEG Huffman encodings, along with dozens of combinations of each.  There are way too many variables in JPEG images to get into.

Unfortunately, there's not going to be a good answer to this question.  There's just not enough information to give a definitive answer.  Even if there was, it would be extremely application specific, or worse, *interaction* with your application specific.

Comment: Re: "PNGs do *not* have to be compressed though, which is the concept of a lossless PNG": That makes it sound like you choose *either* compression *or* losslessness; but in reality, PNGs normally (always?) use lossless compression.

Comment: Good distinction, this is correct.  The compression of data in a PNG is lossless, which is not true of every (most) JPEG encoding.  I simply meant that the data does not have to have any compression.